# Django Rest Framework's Pagination gives less then page size

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm having a problem with Django Rest Framework's Pagination class.

Versions:

- Django 1.9.2
- Django Rest Framework 3.3.2

Here is my Custom pagination class.

pagination.py:

```
from rest_framework import pagination
class VideoPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page'
    max_page_size = 10000
```

settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': ('rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}
```

In my views.py, I have a ListAPIView that lists the all video models and it uses my custom paginator.

views.py:

```
class explore(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ExploreVideoSerializer
    pagination_class = VideoPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.kwargs['category']
        if category == 'all':
            return Video.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        else:
            return Video.objects.filter(category=category).order_by('-date')

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {"request": self.request}
```

The problem is, When I make a request to this view, in first page it gives 10 items which is what I want. Then on the second page and third page, it gives less than 10 items.

For example, there are 16 video items. In the first request, it gives the first 10 of them. In the second page's request, it gives 2 of them. It also says there is another page and gives another 3 of them. In page 4, it gives 4 of them. What might be the reason for such behaviour? I couldn't fix it so that I'm asking for your help.

Not: In the first url, I do not add page number. next url is directly ?page=2. So i guess it is not using the ?page=1 but when I make a request for ?page=1 it gives only 1 model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `page_size_query_param = 'page'`. Here you are saying that the page should be of size `page`. So a URL with `?page=2` will give you a `page_size` of 2.

What you want is [`page_query_param`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#configuration). But its default is `page`, so if you remove this line everything should work.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was like page_query_param. Thank you for your answer, I must've miss it while reading the documentation.

Comment: One question. Why are you using a CustomPagination at all? Using the  DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS will give you a page_size=10 already.

Comment: This is just for example, I have couple of queries which have different page sizes. I didn't now that I could change the page_size dynamically until now :)

Answer (score 1):

Another problem in the code is:

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': ('rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',),
```

should be:

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
```